# How to create a custom method and items for a custom object in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a custom object with custom method and key value pair inside that method in powershell.

```
$mymethod= @{
MemberName = "mymethod"
MemberType = 'ScriptMethod'
Value = {'Test'}
Force = $true
}
Update-TypeData -TypeName 'Dummy' @mymethod
$test = [PsCustomObject][Ordered]@{PsTypeName = 'Dummy'}
```

So this creates and object like 
$test.mymethod() with the value "Test"

What I am trying is to create like below:

```
    $test.mymethod('key1')='value1'
    $test.mymethod('key2')='value2'
```

Any help?

Comment: PowerShell 5+ has `class` which would enable you to create instance objects with methods. What is the output of `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`?

Comment: Looks to me like what you actually want isn't a method, but a property that is a hashtable: `$test = [PSCustomObject]@{'foo' = @{}}; $test.foo['key1'] = 'value1'`.

Comment: As an aside: you don't need the `[ordered]` before the hashtable literal (`@{ ... }`) that you cast to `[pscustomobject]`, because `[pscustomobject] { ... }` is syntactic sugar that _implicitly_ preserves the key-definition order in the resulting object's ordering of properties.

Answer (score 3):

To **answer the question generically** (even though the specific use case may warrant a simpler solution, as demonstrated in [TheIncorrigible1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51661281/45375)):

<sup>Note: In the code below I'm assuming that by `$test.mymethod('key1')='value1'` you actually meant to say that you want `$test.mymethod('key1')` to *return* `'value1'`, given that using a method call as the LHS of an assignment doesn't make sense.</sup>

---

[lit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit) mentions a **PSv5+ alternative: defining a [`[class]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes)**:

```
# Define the class.
class Dummy { 
 [string] mymethod([string] $key) { return @{ key1='value1'; key2='value2' }[$key] }
}

# Instantiate it
$test = [Dummy]::new()

# Call the method
$test.mymethod('key2') # -> 'value2'
```

---

If you do want to use [**PowerShell's ETS** (extended type system)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml), as in your question (which is your only option in PSv4-, short of embedded C# code via `Add-Type`):

Perhaps the only hurdle was not knowing how to define a *parameter* for the method (use a `param()` block) and possibly how to access the instance on which the method is invoked (use `$this`); both techniques are demonstrated below:

```
# Define a type named 'Dummy' and attach a script method named 'mymethod'
$mymethod = @{
  MemberName = 'mymethod'
  MemberType = 'ScriptMethod'
  # Note the use of param() to define the method parameter and
  # the use of $this to access the instance at hand.
  Value      = { param([string] $key) $this.Dict[$key] }
  Force      = $true
}
Update-TypeData -TypeName 'Dummy' @mymethod

# Create a custom object and give it an ETS type name of 'Dummy', which
# makes the mymethod() method available.
$test = [PsCustomObject] @{ PsTypeName = 'Dummy'; Dict = @{ key1='value1'; key2='value2' } } 

$test.mymethod('key2')  # -> 'value2'
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @Ansgar Wiechers's comment, it sounds like you're trying to recreate a dictionary, of which .NET has plenty:

```
$test = [pscustomobject]@{
    bar = [ordered]@{
    }
}
```

In action:

```
$test.bar.Add('key1', 'value1')
$test.bar.Add('key2', 'value2')
```

Output:

```
> $test
>> bar
>> ---
>> {key1, key2}

> $test.bar
>> Name    Value
>> ----    -----
>> key1    value1
>> key2    value2
```

Comment: As a footnote, `@{}` is a literal hashtable, which is just another key/value dictionary.